# Logic Needed for execution of Problems

Tags: unix, sybase

I have a table with four Columns.
Branch,Date1,Date2,Date3

We have a unix script corresponding to each Branch.
Date values in Columns can be 31Dec, 1jan and other than that.

We have to launch unix script for each branch and scripts with same date value can run together.

So I have to launch all scripts with same dates at once for all branches. After scripts for one date values have finished, I need to launch for next date.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: What problem are you having with that exactly? An example would be good, and an explanation of what exactly you're not managing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$ISQL "SELECT Date1 FROM mytab UNION SELECT Date2 FROM mytab UNION SELECT Date3 FROM mytab" | while read Date
do
 (
   print "Doing Date $Date"
   $ISQL "SELECT branch FROM mytab WHERE '$Date' IN (Date1,Date2,Date3)" | while read Branch
   do
      my_big_unix_script.ksh $Branch || touch /tmp/oh-dear &

   done

   wait

   [[ ! -f /tmp/oh-dear ]]

  ) || exit 1
done
```

where $ISQL is whatever method your unix shell set-up has for running a piece of sql (maybe a wrapper round isql, or whatever.)